# Lazarus: реализация Drag & Dock

Tags: windows, pascal, lazarus, delphi, linux

Необходимо сделать "отстегивающиеся" панельки инструментов в кроссплатформенном приложении (`GTK2`).

Что я сделал: кинул на форму `TPanel`, установил у нее `DockSite := true`. Кинул на панель `TToolBar`, установил у него `DragKind = dkDock` и `DragMode := dmAutomatic`.

В чем проблема: `ToolBar` прекрасно "отстегивается" и становится окном, но вот обратно его засунуть на панель не удается. Думаю, что копать надо в сторону того, чтобы отловить `OnStartDock/OnEndDock` у панели и `OnMouseDown/OnStartDrag/OnEndDrag` у тулбара.

Так что же делать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить AnchorDocking пакет.